# VIM Single Compile command from insert mode

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm following [Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 1) - 6.2 Insert mode maps](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29#Insert_mode_maps), and there it says:

```
The <C-R>= command doesn't create a new undo point.
You can also call Vim functions using the <C-R>= command:

:inoremap <F2> <C-R>=MyVimFunc()<CR>
```

I'm trying to use this to call `SingleCompile#Compile()` like:

```
map! <F5> <C-R>=SingleCompile#Compile()<CR>
```

It's working, but the problem is that when I get back to insert mode, a `0` character is inserted as a side-effect.

Why is this and how can I avoid it?

**EDIT:**

I'm using `<C-R>` because it doesn't create a undo point and has the purpose of calling a function instead of entering a command like `<C-O>` does. I don't want to create a undo point.

**EDIT:**

I've updated the VIM wiki based on the ternary operator trick provided by Ingo Karkat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit return value of a function is `0`. You need to either modify `SingleCompile#Compile()` or write a wrapper that returns the empty string:

```
function! SingleCompileWrapper()
    call SingleCompile#Compile()
    return ''
endfunction

map! <F5> <C-R>=SingleCompileWrapper()<CR>
```

An alternative clever trick is to evaluate the function inside the `?:` ternary operator:

```
map! <F5> <C-R>=SingleCompile#Compile()?'':''<CR>
```

Comment: I think your solution is almost there, I just don't want to create a wrapper every time. Do you know how can I create a general wrapper that would call some function I give?

Comment: Your trick is not working for me, I hearing the error beep after entering <F5>

Comment: How many of these functions do you have? You can write a generic wrapper taking a funcref, but the mapping won't become prettier. Maybe appending `<BS>` (as in my other answer) is really the way to go for ya?!

Comment: Now, I'll need 2, but futurely, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, your trick is working, I've let the <C-O> change there and have forget about it. Changing back to <C-R> solved.

Answer (score 1):

The '0' is the return value of the function, which is naturally inserted into the buffer when called in insert mode

Use <C-O> instead of <C-R> to leave the insert mode for the comand

Comment: I'm using <C-R> because it doesn't create a undo point and has the purpose of calling a function instead of entering a command like <C-O> does. I don't want to create a undo point.

Comment: and thanks for the why part. I'm still hoping for a ideal response that would ignore the return value of the function from inserting into the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend that approach, but how about the redneck solution (just delete the `0` after-the-fact):

```
map! <F5> <C-R>=SingleCompile#Compile()<CR><BS>
```

Seriously, for those situations where `<C-R>` cannot be used, and you have to leave insert mode, `:undojoin` may help.

Comment: I'll pass this one because I don't want to :q! because of that 0 that blinked. But I'll take look at :undojoin, thanks